# Multiple searching using req.params node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, parameters

I am fairly new to Node.js and I want to execute multiple searches. I try to use `req.params` to get the search values from the textbox, but my code is not working. I tried to console the `req.params.city` , but nothing is displayed. I am using MySQL database.

Please see my code below:

***Index.js***

```
  router.get('/searche/:city/:date',function(req,res){
  let q = [req.params.city];
  console.log(q)
  db.query('SELECT  city_name, state_name, party_name, price, image, 
address, full_name  FROM register natural join party where userid = id and city_name LIKE "%'+req.params.city+'%" ' ,function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.render('test', {party: rows});
  });
 });
```

***form.ejs***

```
  <form action="/searche"  autocomplete="off">
        <input id="city" type="text" name="city" placeholder='Try "Minneapolis"'>
        <input placeholder="Choose Date" class="textbox-n" name = "date" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" id="date">
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton"> <i class="fa fa search"></i></button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably confusing `params` and `body`.

`params` is for `PATH parameters` used to parametrize the request path, say in your example, `/searche/london/08-25-2019`

Form data *usually* goes as `body` unless, ofcourse, you modify it somehow. So you can do:

```
router.get('/searche',function(req,res) {
  // req.body.city gets you city input
  ...
}
```

Note: You would have to mount `body-parser` or `express`'s inbuilt like `express.json()`

Answer (score 0):

single quote in on wrong place, change this :

```
"%'+req.params.city+'%" '
```

to

```
`"...'%"+ req.params.city+ "%'"`
```

result :

```
db.query("SELECT  city_name, state_name, party_name, price, image, address, full_name  FROM register natural join party where userid = id and city_name LIKE '%"+ req.params.city+ "%'",()=> ...)
```